# Any online recording of [ʀ̆]?

Tags: reference-request, consonants, hebrew

Strangely, the [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uvular_flap) doesn't contain any recording for it (usually it has a recording for each consonant or vowel).

Background: I'm **a native Hebrew speaker** who's interested in pronunciation, especially American-English pronunciation (with focus on GenAm/Midwestern Accents) and Modern Israeli Hebrew pronunciation.

From my decades of hearing Hebrew, I got into the conclusion that the Modern Hebrew ***ר*** is **not** the Voiced uvular fricative([ʁ]) sound, but it actually has a vowel quality to it, like the English [ɹ ]. when pronounced "correctly" (or natively), the Resh has no "friction" sound, and it's very smooth, almost like a back-palatal vowel.

Someone on the internet has suggested that Modern Hebrew ר is actually voiced uvular flap instead, and I would like to test it with some audio recording, to compare (my) Resh to this sound.

My question is: Is there an online recording of the sound voiced uvular flap open to the public?

thanks

Comment: Modern Hebrew is reputed to realise that phoneme as a uvular trill, approximant or fricative. It is most popular in language description to call it a trill if it classes as a liquid. Ladefoged & Maddieson do not even suggest that "uvular flap" is an attested thing distinct from trill. (This comment pertains to the original title which asked about the tap: it's not clear what the question is supposed to be).

Comment: I would guess you are actually hearing an approximant. Non-sibilant fricatives and approximants at the same POA seem to rarely contrast. The uvular approximant is written as ʁ or more narrowly as ʁ̞. English ɹ is also classified as an approximant

Comment: @sumelic, sorry, but I guess my phonological knowledge isn't vast enough to understand your response. Hebrew Resh is definitely not what the narrator in Wikipedia pronounces in the ʁ page. there's too much friction there.

Comment: @sumelic and even so, I think you're on to something, [ɰ] sounds *exactly* how I pronounce it (it's classified as approximant velar, not uvular) . I still want to hear how [ʀ̆] sounds like, though.

Comment: The point is since there is no real thing "uvular flap" [ʀ̆], you can't hear it. It's a theoretical construct. You can hear [ʀ] in real languages (described in IPA as a uvular trill – there is no uvular approximant). You can also hear a uvular fricative, IPA [ʁ]. I also strongly urge people to not take "guy off the street" Wiki contributions to be in any way authoritative.

Comment: @user6726: Oh, there is no uvular approximant? I guess I was misled by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_uvular_fricative) yet again. Is there some articulatory reason why an uvular approximant is technically impossible to produce? Other sources aside from Wikipedia seem to have used the term, e.g. [Distinctive Feature Theory](https://books.google.com/books?id=5_N7sRKJ7I0C&pg=PA336&lpg=PA336&dq=%22uvular+approximant%22&source=bl&ots=-UgmXZDSTV&sig=cXSdZpzRCHrLDtcx8xYbBb4BV4A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-vbzvi_7YAhVJd6wKHQxpBb0Q6AEIVTAH#v=onepage&q=%22uvular%20approximant%22&f=false)

Comment: Yeah, Wiki again... always consult the official IPA, that's my motto. IPA seems to use a "burden of proof" model, where you have to prove that the thing exists, not that it is physically possible. Uvular approximant is an empty box, not a greyed-out box (see also bilabial and pharyngeal approximant). I am not sure if there is any record of debate over these issues, pertaining to why things are the way they are; perhaps in JIPA.

Comment: @user6726: Hmm ... I don't think the IPA lacking a dedicated letter for a particular phone is grounds for saying that "there is no" such phone. The base IPA letters aren't meant to be a definition or categorization of all possible phones (e.g. my understanding is that there are no distinct base IPA letters for Basque *s* and *z,* so they have to be transcribed with diacritics). From your comment, I supposed you meant that there was some theoretical, as opposed to just notational basis for rejecting the use of the term "uvular approximant".

Comment: @user6726 I'm OK with the fact that Wikipedia is not that accurate, and yet, the page I linked gives few "real" examples from real worlds that [ʀ̆] is a part of them. are these examples wrong as well?

Comment: Hi, you can search for pronunciation of the words listed in the wiki page you gave, I found the pronunciation of `Ehre` https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/De-Ehre.ogg